# Google Map NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I wanna show current location of device and use this code below. Unfortunatly I have **NullPointerException** logcat error in getMap() method. Whats wrong? How solve this problem?

**Thanks for any help!**

**Logcat Error**:

```
Process: www.smartavenue.com, PID: 2138
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{www.smartavenue.com/www.smartavenue.com.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
            at www.smartavenue.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:149)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    private GoogleMap _gMap;
    private int _mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Google Map API v2
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        Location location = null;

        if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("GPSINFO")) {
            location = (Location)extras.get("GPSINFO");
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        _gMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        _gMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        _gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        _gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        _gMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        _gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        _gMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        _gMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
        _gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        _gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        LatLng sfLatLng = null;
        if(location != null){
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            sfLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(addresses != null){
                _gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(sfLatLng)
                        .title("Position in " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2))
                        .snippet(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
            }else{
                _gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(sfLatLng)
                        .title("Position")
                        .snippet("No address is available")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
            }
            _gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sfLatLng, 13));
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<fragment
      android:id="@+id/googleMap"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="www.smartavenue.com">
    <!--Google Play Services-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <permission
        android:name="www.smartavenue.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:name="www.smartavenue.com.push_notification.ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <!--MainActivity-->
        <activity
            android:name="www.smartavenue.com.MainActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <!--SplashScreen Activity-->
        <activity android:name="www.smartavenue.com.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Google API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="KEY"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method

Because not calling `setContentView` before accessing `SupportMapFragment` from current Activity layout. Call `setContentView` by passing `activity_main` layout :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Google Map API v2
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    Location location = null;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ....
  }
```

Comment: xD I just forget to wrote it here in post but I have it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek : In `AndroidManifest` have you add `<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="place your API KEY" />` ??

Comment: I updated my post with code of manifest file. Can you Check it now?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek : where you have `setContentView` method ?

Comment: I have it in onCreat method of MainActivity. I think that I have problems cause I use ActionBarActivity. How do you think? By the way I add setContentView to my post.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029015/app-crash-when-trying-to-access-mapfragment probably

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek: or try to extends `ActionBarFragmentActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: ActionBarFragmentActivity gave my a lot of errors in code. I am not sure that its what I need. So now I dont know what to do now. =(