# Google Maps getMap returns null

Tags: android, google-maps

**UPDATED**
I read many topics but nothing helped or I didn't understand what to do. I get null and I don't know why. I am just learning so please help me.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.text.fragments.MapFragment.initilizeMap(MapFragment.java:52)
        at com.example.text.fragments.MapFragment.onViewCreated(MapFragment.java:46)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:971)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:488)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:792)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:596)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:556)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:778)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

This is Fragment where I implemented getMap

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // here, as doc say, the map can be initialized, or the service is not available
        initilizeMap();
    }

     private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mGoogleMap) {
        googleMap = mGoogleMap;
    }
}
```

This is map_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBUeq6ANw9MyK9vwB4phnSOkp6e_UccN4E" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I use sliding tabs and in one tab has to have map. I create this map in this part of code in ViewPagerAdapter:

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(mNumbOfTabs == 3) {
            if (position == 0) {
                A a = new A();
                return a;
            } else if (position == 1) {
                B b = new B();
                return b;
            } else {
                MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
                return mapFragment;
            }
    }
```

Comment: move `initilizeMap();` in `onCreateView(......)`

Comment: You should be using `getMapAsync` rather than `getMap` since Play Services 6.5.

Comment: I did that, still the same logs.

Comment: Did you try this Not the exact solution but I guess it is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029015/app-crash-when-trying-to-access-mapfragment

Comment: What I should give as a parameter in getMapAsync ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the 6.5 version of Play Services Google [recommends using of asynchronous getting of GoogleMap](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2014/11/google-play-services-65.html) and `getMap()` is now deprecated. As [stkent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2911458/stkent)'s mentioned you have to call `getMapAsync(this)`.

As this method asynchronous you need some callback for this method, that's why also you have to make your fragment implementing `OnMapReadyCallback` and in the method `onMapReady()` of these callbacks you can get reference to the map.

Also change line `((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);` to `((SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);` 'cause inside fragment you have to use ChildFragmentManager.

Comment: I did this:     @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mGoogleMap) {
        googleMap = mGoogleMap;
    }
            });
But still the same problem

Comment: try to change line `((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);` to line `((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);`

Comment: Oh, remove `getActivity()` call, sorry. `((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);`

Comment: It works, can you help me how to add for example button on the map?

Comment: did you try to look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker guide?

Comment: I read but not everything, but I want text view or button or whatever is it possible ?

Comment: you can add marker to your map and this guide shows how to do it. In case of problems post new question, but not in this thread 'cause it's another question not related with original

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, with google maps v2 you should use `getExtendedMap()`instead. Try this.

Comment: I don't have this method

Comment: @Mateus Brandao: `getExtendedMap()` is a method for *Android Maps Extensions*: https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/ not *Google Maps Android API v2*