# GoogleMap will be null on Android API 23

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to get `GoogleMap` on Android API 23 but following line gives me null and that's weird, because there was no problem on API 22 or maybe last build of Google Play Services.

```
GoogleMap mMapFragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_view)).getMap();
```

**And the layout:**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

**Log**

```
09-03 07:15:52.128    4540-4540/com.XXX E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.XXX, PID: 4540, 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.XXX/com.XXX.activities.ShopNewActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getUiSettings()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getUiSettings()' on a null object reference
at com.XXX.activities.ShopNewActivity.onCreate(ShopNewActivity.java:211)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Can you post the logs or more info to point out the issue?

Comment: Are you calling `findFragmentById()` in `onCreate()`? What I'm wondering is if the map is instantiated or not in `onCreate()`, which might cause `getMap()` to be `null` at this point in the lifecycle. I would try possibly moving the call to `getMap()` to the `onResume()` function. Also, if you have some logs from logcat, that would help in tracking down the issue.

Comment: Actually, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30077744/1344273) might help. It looks like the `getMap()` function is deprecated and you should use `getMapAsync()` instead.

Comment: @Bradford2000 Thanks. I think the method is deprecated but no warning supplied! I cannot test the solution right now but I will soon and let you know about the result. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this snippet as commented by Brad:

1. Implement `OnMapReadyCallback` interface.
2. In `onCreate()` method add the following code to get the GoogleMap asynchronously once it's ready:

   `MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`
3. Once the map is ready to be used you will get a callback thru `onMapReady()` in which GoogleMap is accessible.